# IBM MQ qmgr failing to start on Windows 10 with error as AMQ6119: An internal IBM MQ error has occurred () exitvalue = 71

Tags: ibm-mq

I am using Windows 10 (despite MQ reporting it as Windows 8), the user starting the service is part of mqm group and was the same user used to do all the mq administrative work.

**The FDC error file in the qmgr logs is showing these.**

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                             |
| IBM MQ First Failure Symptom Report                                         |
| =========================================                                   |
|                                                                             |
| Date/Time         :- Sun October 04 2020 17:57:20 E. Africa Standard Time   |
| UTC Time          :- 1601823440.226000                                      |
| UTC Time Offset   :- 180 ((UNKNOWN))                                        |
| Host Name         :-                                                        |
| Operating System  :- Windows 8 Enterprise x64 Edition, Build 9200           |
| PIDS              :- 5724H7251                                              |
| LVLS              :- 9.0.0.0                                                |
| Product Long Name :- IBM MQ for Windows (x64 platform)                      |
| Vendor            :- IBM                                                    |
| O/S Registered    :- 1                                                      |
| Data Path         :- D:\Installations\IBM\DataFiles\MQ                      |
| Installation Path :- D:\Installations\IBM\MQ                                |
| Installation Name :- Installation1    (1)                                   |
| License Type      :- Production                                             |
| Probe Id          :- ZT473001                                               |
| Application Name  :- MQM                                                    |
| Component         :- zutUpdateQMXADLLEntry                                  |
| SCCS Info         :- F:\build\slot1\p900_P\src\lib\zu\amqzutb0.c,           |
| Line Number       :- 4718                                                   |
| Build Date        :- May 12 2016                                            |
| Build Level       :- p900-L160512.4                                         |
| Build Type        :- IKAP - (Production)                                    |
| UserID            :- mquser                                                 |
| Process Name      :- D:\Installations\IBM\MQ\bin64\strmqm.exe               |
| Arguments         :- -x -d all IIBQM                                        |
| Addressing mode   :- 64-bit                                                 |
| Process           :- 00013196                                               |
| Thread            :- 00000001                                               |
| Session           :- 00000001                                               |
| QueueManager      :- IIBQM                                                  |
| UserApp           :- FALSE                                                  |
| Last HQC          :- 0.0.0-0                                                |
| Last HSHMEMB      :- 0.0.0-0                                                |
| Last ObjectName   :-                                                        |
| Major Errorcode   :- xecF_E_UNEXPECTED_SYSTEM_RC                            |
| Minor Errorcode   :- OK                                                     |
| Probe Type        :- MSGAMQ6119                                             |
| Probe Severity    :- 2                                                      |
| Probe Description :- AMQ6119: An internal IBM MQ error has occurred (IIBQM) |
| FDCSequenceNumber :- 0                                                      |
| Arith1            :- 5 5                                                    |
| Comment1          :- IIBQM                                                  |
|                                                                             |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Try starting it in an admin CMD prompt.

Comment: Thanks @JoshMc, I am able to start it up with the admin command prompt.
I am suspecting some Windows updates are messing me up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FDC reports that MQ is unable to access somthing (In this case, arith1 == 5 == access denied). The function doing this is trying to update a particular registry key which is outside the MQ tree and which is updated by the MQ installation.

1. It might potentially be caused if you have configured MQ so the user that the service runs under is not in the local mqm group, although that would not be a good thing, so you might want to fix that. To fix that, you would bring up an elevated (ie use the "run as administrator", not just one where you are logged in as an administrator) command prompt and issue

> net localgroup mqm  /ADD

Once you have done this, you might need to reboot the machine for it to be effective. Try restarting the service manually once, and if it doesnt help, try the reboot.

2. I've also seen this problem after a windows update which reset the registry permissions on a key which the MQ installation has previously updated, preventing it being updated when the queue manager starts.

When this occurs, depending on the version of MQ you might also get an error message in the global errors log (and possibly the event log) saying:

> AMQ6509E: Unable to update registry value.
>
> EXPLANATION: An attempt was made to update the value of 'WebSphere MQ
> QMgr (myqm)' in registry key
> 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSDTC\XADLL' to
> 'C:\mqinstalls\MQ9120\bin64\amqmtsxatm.dll', however a problem was
> encountered when doing so. The system return code was 5. ACTION:
> Verify that the permissions on registry key
> 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSDTC\XADLL' allow the
> executing user to modify values within it. Executing 'crtmqdir -f -a'
> under a local computer administrator user account will restore any
> missing permissions required by MQ.

You need to follow the instructions in the error message, ie To fix that, bring up an elevated (ie use the "run as administrator", not just one where you are logged in as an administrator) command prompt and issue

> {path to MQ installation}\bin64\crtmqdir -f -a

If your version of MQ does not have such a binary, manually browse in regedit to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSDTC\XADLL and right mouse button on XADLL->permissions and give mqm rights to query and set values for that key.

Comment: the user is already added to the mqm group and is the same user we have been using for the MQ administration.
I could not find any useful entries in the event viewer apart from something saying "Service could not start".

I am going to check the registry as specified and revert

Comment: Yeah it'll have to be by hand. Apologies - I checked and crtmqdir  -f -a options basically fix up anything wrong it finds, but as far as I can see the reapply of permissions for the XADLL key was first introduced in 9.1.0.0